# C++ Variable Array

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, variables, buffer

I am trying to write a socket system that is to handle extremely long messages (it handles a chat system). I am trying to use a const int to initialize an array, which DOES compile, but I am warned about ISO C++ forbidding it. Can someone shed some light on the situation?

Here is an example of how it would be used (this is to avoid writing a byte-remaining multi-recieve system (which I already have, but I feel this would be more efficient)).

```
    const int BUFFERLEN = atoi(api_GETVALUE(1,inbuffer).c_str()); //that is my API call
       if(BUFFERLEN != -1) { //it returns "-1" on error
          char INBUFFER[BUFFERLEN];
          recv(SOCK,INBUFFER,sizeof(INBUFFER),0);
       }
```

Is this acceptable to do at all, or should I stick with the multi-recieve-until-done method?

Thanks,
Collin

Comment: Either do multiple smaller receives, or allocate the buffer dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 const int BUFFERLEN = atoi(api_GETVALUE(1,inbuffer).c_str()); //that is my API call
       if(BUFFERLEN != -1) { //it returns "-1" on error
          std::vector<char> INBUFFER(BUFFERLEN);
          recv(SOCK,INBUFFER.data(),INBUFFER.size(),0);
       }
```

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who posted, I understand now. I didn't even realize I could use a vector to receive data from a socket, that is exactly what I needed. I have been writing most of my code in C-style as I haven't learned some of the more helpful STL features yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a C++ array the size must be known at compile time. Otherwise, you need to use dynamic allocation. `const` doesn't necessarily mean that `BUFFERLEN` is a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use a const int to initialize an array, which DOES compile, but I am warned about ISO C++ forbidding it. Can someone shed some light on the situation?

It is because the `const int` in your program is not actually constant expression (a value which is known at compile time), which means the declared array in your program is Variable Length Array (VLA) which is not allowed in ISO C++. Your program compiles because your compiler provides VLA as extension.

What you can use is called `std::vector<char>`.

So instead of,

```
char INBUFFER[BUFFERLEN];  //old code
```

you can use

```
std::vector<char> INBUFFER(BUFFERLEN); //new code
```

and instead of,

```
recv(SOCK,INBUFFER,sizeof(INBUFFER),0); //old code
```

you can write:

```
recv(SOCK, &INBUFFER[0], INBUFFER.size(),0); //new code
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ 98 does not allow variable length arrays. It doesn't matter that your int is a "const", because the size cannot be determined in advance. Creating a wrapper around char* which manages the allocation and unallocation of its own memory is an acceptable solution.